# tensorflow change checkpoint location

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

i was wondering if theres a way to indicate to your training models(in tensorflow) or to tensorflow configuration in general where to store checkpoint files, i was tranining a neural network and got the errors:
InternalError: Error writing (tmp) checkpoint file: /tmp/tmpn2cWXm/model.ckpt-500-00000-of-00001.tempstate12392765014661958578: Resource exhauste
and
ERROR:tensorflow:Got exception during tf.learn final checkpoint .

And also im getting operating system alerts(debian linux) about low disk space so i asume that the problem is that my disk got full with checkpoint files but i have serveral partitions in my disk with enough space and would like to move checkpoint files there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your save path as the second argument of `tf.train.Saver.save(sess, 'your/save/path', ...)`. Similarly, you can restore your previously saved variables passing your restore path as the second argument of `tf.train.Saver.restore(sess, 'your/restore/path')`.

Please, see [TensorFlow Saver documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) and [these saving and restoring examples](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/variables/index.html#saving-and-restoring) for further details.

Comment: The two links you provided give 404 now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old query that I stumbled upon today while searching for some other issue. Anyway, I thought I will put down my thoughts in case it helps someone in the future.

You can specify the model directory while constructing your regressor. This can be any location on your filesystem where you have write permission and enough space (the events file needs quite a bit). For ex:

```
dnn_regressor = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
  ...,
  model_dir="/tmp/mydata"
```

)